# ImageResier mode option

Tags: asp.net, .net, imageresizer

We are using the wonderful ImageResizer and wondered if there was a way to crop images based on whether they are portrait or Landscape. If the Image is Landscape we like to use the crop option otherwise for portrait, we would like to use canvas or max option. something like :

```
?width=500&height=300&mode=depends&landscape=crop&portrait=canvas
```

Is there anywhere in the api which we can hook into to achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're referring to this?: http://imageresizing.net/?

Comment: Personally? No, sorry, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully, someone will know.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write [an ImageResizer plugin](http://imageresizing.net/docs/extend/basics) to implement your logic (overrding Layout* methods in BuilderExtension), but this certainly isn't something that would have an API syntax.

Perhaps if you shared more information about what you're trying to do, we can find a simpler solution that doesn't involve conditional logic?